# Dynamically edit SQL Query based off of model value in ASP.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.net and SQL Query. In SQL I have table similar to these, named Departments and SubDepartments

| DepartmentID | DepartmentName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Department1 |
| 2 | Department2 |

| SubDepartmentID | SubDepartmentName | DepartmentID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SubDepartment1 | 2 |
| 2 | SubDepartment2 | 2 |
| 3 | SubDepartment3 | 1 |

In asp.net I need to run a query similar to this

```
SELECT SubDepartmentID FROM SubDepartments WHERE DepartmentID = '2'
```

Which would give me the result

| SubDepartmentID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

HOWEVER, I need to do this dynamically like this

```
SELECT SubDepartmentID FROM SubDepartments WHERE DepartmentID = '*Dynamic Value*'
```

where the Dynamic Value is given based off the dropdown value of a model in my view.

I have tried to look at different ways to dynamically edit an SQL query in asp.net but nothing seems to be working for me.

My goal is eventually to have a department ddl, sub department ddl, machine ddl, equipment ddl, then problem ddl. I will eventually a need a query that reads all those values and returns only the problems that belong to the selected department, sub department, machine, and equipment. Completing just the connection between the department and sub department should be enough to figure out how to do it though.

EDIT:
My view code so far is this

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

```
<script type="text/jscript">
    $(function () {
    $("#Departmentddl").change(function () {
    alert($('option:selected').val());
    });
    });
</script>
```

```
<div class="form-group" id="Departmentddl">
    <label asp-for="DepartmentId" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="DepartmentId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.DepartmentId"></select>

</div>
```

```
<div class="container" id="SubDepartmentddlOther">
    <div class="form-group" id="SubDepartmentddl">
        <label asp-for="SubDepartmentId" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="SubDepartmentId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.SubDepartment"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: ViewBag.Department works, but ViewBag.SubDepartment has no values.

I should also add that my controller is titled "RecordEntriesController"

EDIT AGAIN:

I am using this right now to try to fill in the dropdown list. It is working but it is not using my variables NumberValue and NameLabel. How do I make those correct? This is my JSON and the jscript is following. I created the JSON in my controller so it can be changed if it is not formatted correctly.

```
{"NumberValue":"5","NameLabel":"SubDepartment1"},{"NumberValue":"8","NameLabel":"SubDepartment2"}
```

```
<script type="text/jscript">
    $(function () {
        $("#ddlDepartments").change(function () {
            var selectedid = $('option:selected').val();
            if (selectedid > 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/RecordEntries/PopulateddlSubDepartments",
                    data: {
                        id: selectedid
                    },
                    type: "Post",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                        var ddldist = $('#ddlSubDepartments');
                            $.each(data, function (NumberValue, NameLabel) {

                                 ddldist.append(
                                     $('<option></option>').val(NumberValue).html(NameLabel)
                            );
                        });

                    },
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What technology do you use to communicate with databases? Is asp mvc?

Comment: @MeysamAsadi Yes, I am using MVC

Comment: Your question is not clear, do you use entityframework or ado?

Comment: Entity Framework. Sorry, this is my first project and I barely even know what some of this means. I am using the MVC controller with views using Entity Framework. It is asp.net Core too if that makes a difference.

Comment: you work code first or model first?

Comment: I created my SQL server first then used the scaffold-dbcontext to create models. Now I am just trying to turn my main form into a dynamic form.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0 Perhaps I could do something like this to pass the values into a controller then write an SQL Query that is dynamic? I am not great with MVC relationships.

Comment: So do you work with asp mvc or asp core?

Comment: I'm working with core.

Comment: see https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/binding-data-to-dropdown-list-in-asp-net-core-mvc-web-application/ .Wherever you have a problem, tell me so that I can explain it in response

Comment: I am reading through this and it appears that this is not quite what I need. I can populate my first dropdown for Departments using ViewBag. I have completed that step. It is reading the selected value of the Departments ddl in the controller that I am having troubles with.

Comment: see this https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Core-Get-selected-Value-of-DropDownList.aspx

Comment: I did not work with asp core, so I do not know the best way to do it, but you can easily do it with jQuery and partial view. I can give you a complete example of how the two dropdownlists work

Comment: When I was looking at options jQuery seemed like the best one. As long as I can pull the model value into it it should be no problem. I am just not experienced with it

Comment: I have used jscript in order to get a the selected value from my selected ddl. Now I just don't know how to pass that value into a query in my controller.

Comment: Please enter your view code and script in the question

Comment: I just added them in.

Comment: I entered the answer, see the output you want

Comment: @Meysam Asadi I have just made an edit if you know the answer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change script to this :

Replace the `url:"/Home/GetDropDownList"` with the name of your controller and action

```
<script type="text/jscript">
  $(function() {
    $("#Departmentddl").change(function() {
      var selectedid = $('option:selected').val();
      if (selectedid > 0) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "/Home/GetDropDownList",
          data: {
            id: selectedid
          },
          type: "Post",
          dataType: "Json",
          success: function(result) {
             alert(result);
          },
          error: function() {
           
          }
        });
      } 
    });
  });
</script>
```

in your controller

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetDropDownList(int id)
{
   // do work
   return Json("success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  
}
```

Comment: The JsonRequestBehavior is not recognized. I tried adding ```using System.Web.Mvc``` but that adds lots of errors to the rest of my controller. Is there another way to add the reference? I must not be using the correct framework for ```System.Web.Mvc```

Comment: use return Ok("success") or use return new JsonResult("success");

Comment: I'm learning I'm really bad at this lol. Anyway, I've been working on implementing this and just keep getting stuck. I have tried to use raw sql but then I run into an issue converting that to JSON. I'm thinking I may not actually have to use JSON to pass the data back to the view though. I could just use ViewData or ViewBag as long as I can use a where clause in that, which I have not figured out yet.